# Pin dropbox to ubuntu cinnamon 20.04 panel

Tags: panel, cinnamon

Does anybody know how to pin a dropbox folder into Ubuntu cinnamon panel at the bottom?

I pinned nemo, but it keeps opening "home" by default.

Maybe changing the default launcher properties of nemo (or nautilus) might help.